# Добавить поля в таблице User от Django

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, как правильно добавить поля к стандартной таблице User от Django?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: самая лучшая [статья](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/) по кастомизации юзера в джанго

Answer (score 0):

Добавить свое поле к стандартной модели `django.contrib.auth.models.User` можно, используя метод `User.add_to_class()`.

Пример использования:

```py
User.add_to_class('ИМЯ', ЗНАЧЕНИЕ)
```

PS: Протестировано в Django-2.x